# How to get all previous values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Can someone help me out how to achieve the result in given image?

[image]

I have such data. How can I replace all the nulls with all previous date data.
And expected output will be like.

[image]

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Please post table structure and sample data not in image format.  Also what have you tried?   You cant have SQL 2008 and SQL 2012, its one or th eohter

Comment: Also the query you are using to get the above would be helpful to save time for pepole helping you.

Comment: I am using sql server 2014

Comment: Why is the second last column (and all other columns) alternating between .50 and .01?

Comment: @SalmanA those are the random values between 0.01 to 1.0

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't support the `IGNORE NULL`s option in `LAG()` -- which is what you really want.

One method uses `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select . . .,
       coalesce(t.col1, t2.col1) as col1,
       coalesce(t.col2, t2.col2) as col2,
       coalesce(t.col3, t2.col3) as col3,
       coalesce(t.col4, t2.col4) as col4,
       coalesce(t.col5, t2.col5) as col5,
       coalesce(t.col6, t2.col6) as col6
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.col7 < t.col7 and
            t2.col1 is not null
      order by t2.col7 desc
     ) t2;
```

Here is a faster method that works in SQL Server 2012+:

```
select . . .,
       coalesce(t.col1, t2.col1) as col1,
       coalesce(t.col2, t2.col2) as col2,
       coalesce(t.col3, t2.col3) as col3,
       coalesce(t.col4, t2.col4) as col4,
       coalesce(t.col5, t2.col5) as col5,
       coalesce(t.col6, t2.col6) as col6
from (select t.*,
             max(case when t.col1 is not null then t.col7 end) over (order by t.col7) as max_non_null_col7
      from t
     ) t left join
     t t2
     on t2.col7 = t.max_non_null_col7;
```

You can also get rid of join, but it is probably fast with the right index.

Comment: There is no need to do a self join for this. Have a look at the following: The Last non NULL Puzzle (https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle)

Comment: @JasonA.Long . . . The question is tagged SQL Server 2008, which does not support the constructs in that blog.  Further, the ANSI/ISO standard `IGNORE NULLS` is really the best method, but SQL Server does not support that.

Comment: It's tagged SQL Server 2014... But, now that you say that I do see where the vrsion tags were edited a couple hours ago.